# Cannot send request to django api through html and js but it worked through postman

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-rest-framework, request, fetch

I`m struggling with some annoying problem. I`ve writen an api in Django Rest Framework which purpose is to add new user to database. If I`m trying to work with this api with POSTMAN - it is working, but when I`m trying to send a request through fetch func in javascript with same headers and data - it`s showing bad request.... [JS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVTXr.png), [API code + Results of sending through fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6BMf.png), [Serializer code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUwVQ.png), [Exact same request with POSTMAN WORKS PERFECTLY!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yymay.png) [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYy72.png)

CSRF Token been send using official django ajax func which is shown in official doc.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

I`ve been trying literally everything.

1. Content-type been changed multiple times
2. Removed and added a CSRF Token field in fetch
3. Changed content type to enctype

As you can see first-touch connection with api is alive in both cases (word 'inside' in console), but when I`m sending request through javascript - keep getting 400 bad request. ITS NOT BECAUSE SERIALIZER IS NOT VALID - ITS VALID.

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about posting pictures of code (tl;dr: don't).

Comment: "Exact same request" — They **really** aren't the same. Your JavaScript is posting JSON while your Postman screenshot shows you are posting form-data.

Comment: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. ` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask